# Extension of mapping of subset to homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-homomorphism

Is the following proposition true?

Let $V$, $W\neq0$ be vector spaces over some field $F$ and let $S_v \subset V$.
Then if every mapping $f:S_v \to W$ can be uniquely extended to homomorphism $g:V\to W$, $S_v$ is a basis of $V$.

So far I tried to prove only that $S_v$ can contain only linear independent vectors.

I proceed as follows:

Let every mapping $f:S_v \to W$ be extendable to homomorphism $g:V\to W$. Let $B_v=(b_1,...,b_n)$ be a basis of V. Then it's true that $\forall v \in V$ with coordinates ($c_1,...,c_n$):

$g(v) = g(\sum_{ \substack{i\in \hat{n}}}c_ib_i)=\sum_{{i\in \hat{n}}}c_ig(b_i)$

Moreover let $S_v=(s_1,...,s_m)$ and as $g$ is extension of $f$ : $(\forall s \in S_v) (g(s) = f(s))$.

Then $S_v$ can't be linearly dependent because if it is then:

($\exists c_1,...c_m)((\exists i\in \hat{m})(c_i \neq 0 \wedge \sum_{ \substack{j\in \hat{m}}}c_js_j=0 ) \wedge g(\sum_{ \substack{i\in \hat{m}}}c_is_i)=\sum_{ \substack{i\in \hat{m}}}c_if(s_i) = 0)$

and that won't hold for all possible mappings $f$.

Can I somehow proceed further and prove that $S_v$ is basis?

I tried to define a homomorphism on $V$. Knowing that $S_v$ is linearly independent I can extend it to basis $B'_v = (s_1, ..., s_m, b'_{m+1}, ... , b'_n)$ and define $g$ also to map $(b'_{m+1}, ... , b'_n) \to W $.

At the end I will have:

$(\forall v \in V)(\exists c_1,...,c_n) (g(v) = g(\sum_{ {i\in \hat{m}}}c_is_i+\sum_{ {m<j\leq n}}c_jb'_i) = \sum_{ {i\in \hat{m}}}c_if(s_i)+\sum_{ {m<j\leq n}}c_jg(b'_i)))$.

But it won't be a unique extension because I can extend $S_v$ to basis in different ways. So the only option is to have $S_v$ as basis already.

Does this correctly prove that the proposition is true?

**Corrections compared to the first version:** forgot to mention uniqueness of extension, added restriction $W\neq0$.

Comment: What if $W = 0$?

Comment: Then $f$ = $f'$ = 0 and I guess $S_v$ can be also linearly dependent. Is it so?

Comment: Even in the case $V=W$ (or, better, under the appropriate permutation of quantifiers: "given $V$, $S_v\subseteq V$ has the property that *for all* $W$ and all maps $S_v\to W$ et cetera"), you won't get far if you do not require the linear extension to be *unique*.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention uniqueness, could you explain the difference. I updated the hypothesis.

Comment: Which of the two? The different statement or the uniqueness?

Comment: Difference in this case between mentioning uniqueness of homomorphism and not

Comment: I think I understand - uniqueness will affect my possibility to extend $S_v$ to basis of $V$. If it is unique extension then only option I have is that $S_v$ is already a basis. Could you say if it's true.

Comment: Well, if $v\ne 0$ and $W=V$ then $S_v$ always satisfies the hypothesis, but it's never a basis unless $\dim V=1$. Sketch of proof: if $S_v$ were not a basis, the quotient map onto $V/\operatorname{Span}S_v$ would not be the zero map. Depending on hypothesis, you can try to lift it to $V$ or have this directly as a counterexample.

Comment: Could you say what you mean by $v \neq 0$ and "but it's never a basis unless dim$V=1$"? Do you mean that it's never a basis in case that $W \neq V$?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you assume that $dim(W)\ge dim(V)$, as pointed out in the comments. I will assume that $W=V$ as it is the simplest case, and all other cases are a corollary of it.

Let $S_V=\{s_1, \dots \}$. Let $U=Span(S_V)$. Then we have that the map $f:S_V\to V$ given by $v\mapsto v$ can be extended to the identity map $V\to V$, and the map given by projection $V\to U$ both extend $f$, so they must coincide, and $U=Im(Pr_U)=Im(Id)=V$, so $S_V$ is a spanning set.

For independence, assume that $s_i=\sum_{i\neq j} a_js_j$. Then we have a map $f_i:S_V\to V$ given by $s_j\mapsto 0$ for $j\neq i$, and $s_i\mapsto s_i$. By assumption, this extends to $f:V\to V$. So that $s_i=f(s_i)=f(\sum_j a_js_j)=\sum_i a_jf(s_j)=0$. But if $s_i=0$, then the map $f:S_V\to V$ given by $s_i\mapsto 1$ has $1=f(s_i)=f(0)=f(2*0)=f(2s_i)=2$, a contradiction. Thus we have that the $s_j$ are independent, so that $S_V$ forms a basis as desired.

Comment: I don't understand why I must assume that $dim(W) \geq dim(V)$. Therefore I don't understand how to generalize your proof. Could you explain this more. Also it's unclear for me why in your proof you state that projection and identity maps should coincide. Is that because of words "uniquely extended" in the theorem? As I understand these words imply that from every mapping there is only one extension but I think it doesn't mean that mappings should be the same. Please point out where I am wrong here.

Comment: In other words, you can have n-different extensions - one for each of $n$ possible mappings of $S_v$. But you can't have more than $n$.

Comment: Though using my definition of "uniquely extended" the statement seems always false. If we consider zero map of $S_v$ then it can be always extended in a lot of different ways to homomorphism.

Comment: If you have two mappings extending the same map, then they must coincide by definition of uniqueness of the extension. The assumption $dim(W)\ge dim(V)$, since one can find a linear bijection $W=V\oplus U$ for some subspace $U$, and the unique extension of maps to $f:S_V\to V$ follows from $f:S_V\to V\to W$ (note that in each case we can overlook the minor issue of the fact that the extension map lie in $W$ not $V$, by constructing explicitly the extensions we want).

Comment: Ok, I understand why we need to require that $W\neq0$ because otherwise any subset $S_p$ would work. Also I understand why we need to have $dim(W) \geq 1$ - if so we have the choice how to extend $S_p$ if it's not a basis and therefore extension won't be unique. But if for example $dim(W)=1$ and $dim(V)=2$ what can go wrong? we will demand subset to be linearly independent as stated above and for unique extension of $f: S_v \to X$ $S_v$ will have to be a basis. And it seems like everything works.